# Nginx: how to search and replace string variables like str_replace

Tags: nginx

I'm new with nginx and before this question search too much. I want to set a variable equal to `$uri` and search and replace in it some characters, something like this:

```
$my_string = $uri;
$my_string = replace('old','new',$my_string);
```